# setVisibility(View.GONE) is not working in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to show LinearLayout on some items of ListView.

In Adapter code;

```
listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (position == 0)
                    llCurtain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else if (position == 3)
                    llContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else {
                    llCurtain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    llContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

`llCurtain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` works well but `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` is not working.

Comment: Where you set `listitem` , `llCurtain` and `llContainer`?

Comment: what is difference between **llCurtain & llContainer**?

Comment: if you switch from position 0->3 , 3->0 both views will be visible. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @aikutto can you explain more what is your requirement. also post your code. I think, it is better to make a custom adapter class set visibility of of view in your custom adapter.

Comment: @maven llCurtain & llContainer are LinearLayouts. llCurtain should appear in first item's onClick and llContainer should appear in 4th item's onClick.

Comment: so I can't see any difficulty